# How to resize view with UIPanGestureRecognizer and auto layout?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uipangesturerecognizer

Currently I have on the same screen a MapView on the top, a barView on the middle and a TableView on the bottom. When I move the barView, just the barView moves, and when I finish dragging the barView, the mapView and TableView adjust their size.

Now I want to do the same result but I want the mapView and TableView to resize when I'm dragging the barView, not just when I finish.

Is there a solution to do this with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and Autolayout?